# Is it possible to prevent the Microsoft Sync Centre from reporting errors in the Taskbar? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, sync, notification-area, folder-redirection

Our Windows 7 desktops have their desktops redirected to our (SBS 2003) server.

This works well, and we use the Microsoft Sync Centre to ensure that users' files are available even if there is a temporary problem contacting the server.

However, almost 50% of the time, the Sync Centre icons seems to display a sync failure alert in the notification area (for one file). If the Sync Centre is told to run another synchronization, the error immediately disappears. Whatever momentary network glitch caused an issue has already gone (it was not a serious problem).

The red notification shown next to the icon apparently does not get cleared automatically- and users never think to clear it. So it ends up always showing these meaningless error notifications.

Is there a way to configure the Sync Centre so that it never displays sync notifications- if it stops logging sync errors, I probably wouldn't mind that too much either.

I know it is possible to hide the Sync Centre icon from the notification area completely using a [registry hack](http://notepad.softwarevalley.net/view/8/how-to-remove-sync-center-icon.aspx), but it is useful as it allows me to see that the Sync Centre is running- I just want to hide the notification failure alerts.

This is how I want the icon always appear (without any red notifications):

[image]

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: What entries are in `current machine - software - microsoft - windows - currentversion - syncmanager - handlers - {} - defaulticon`

Comment: [take a look at this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)